# How to use Intl.NumberFormat with react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-intl

Im trying to convert a number to price format in react native. How to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat (Intl.NumberFormat) this with react native?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need the international version of JSC:
Android: https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#international-variant

For iOS you'd need to use Intl.js polyfill https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/

Comment: Is there any plugin available ?

Comment: you can use JS polyfill(for default JS engine on Android): https://gist.github.com/evasyuk/e05c230afa578fe42f95e4d8b004356f

Answer (score -1):

Simply install the [intl package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl) for expo building on android.
Then you can use the Intl.NumberFormat as described in the Mozilla Docs.