# Intl.numberformat in React native works fine when running in ios but not in android

Tags: android, react-native, intl

I am developing an app with React Native to run on IOS and Android. I use `Intl.numberformat()` to print currency, and it works smoothly when the app runs on IOS, but I get this error when running on Android: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl`.

How can I make it run in both plataforms?

Comment: possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57881511/12370254

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had faced similar issue. The issue was with Javascript core which runs the react- native. There are two ways to overcome this.

1.**Method 1** You'll have to integrate latest javascript core into your android build or upgrade react native to 0.59

You can find it [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#how-to-use-it-with-my-react-native-app)

2. **Method 2** Add or override the following code in your **app/build.gradle**

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'

Clean build and **react-native run android**

Comment: Only method 2 worked for me. Using RN 0.66

Comment: How could we fix this if the app is using Expo?

Comment: @EstebanChornet Did you find any solution for Expo?

Comment: Installing the intl package solved the issue for me for expo building on android https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl

Comment: I installed `Intl@1.2.5` with `react-native@0.64.x` and it doesn't work for me for some regions like pt-BR on Android. NumberFormat returns a number in the imperial format while it should be metric. On iOS it works though.

Comment: My problem was that the library `Intl` wasn't formatting my numbers correctly for specific regions, All I had to do was to import every locale considered in the beginning of the file like: `import "intl/locale-data/jsonp/pt-BR"` and it worked. With extra steps you can import it dynamically, which then I did, probably better.

Comment: @EstebanChornet you should place your comment as a full answer to the question.